# using ajax to return array or string so I can use it in controller Cakephp 2

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

The case is that I have several banner(ads) in a page, and I need to save to database how many times it is shown in page.
say,

I have banner with id=1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

now everytime the page refresh, it loads to a page banner id = 1, 2, 3. So, I need to take this id so I can save field to database for the view count.

My question is, how to use jquery ajax, to return that id number so I can use it in controller. I have set up in javascript

```
var adId = '1,2,3';
```

Of course I can use ajax and loop it several times and put each id as multiple ajax call, but I don't want to do that. Is there anyway maybe using json or something to get that data so I can use it in controller everytime the page load?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do, or what server side language you use.
You can send data as an array in json format:

```
var adId = [1, 2, 3];
```

in javascript you can use it like a normal array.
If you use PHP on server side, you can apply `json_decode()` to transform that string in json format into an array usable in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your jquery to send data to your controller action.

```
$.get("<?php echo $this->Html->url('controller' => 'ads', 'update_views'); ?>", { id: "1"} );
```

This should be in your controller for example: ads_controller.php

```
function update_views(){
  if isset($_GET['id']){
    $ad_id = $_GET['id'];
    $ad = $this->Ad->read($ad_id);
    $this->Ad->id = $ad_id;
    $this->Ad->saveField('views', $ad['views']+1);
  }
  return false; // not to return a view.
}
```

I did not test this, hope it works. I believe it will. Hope I understood you correctly. Cheers